# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: unitOfWork

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to create a new user and a role and assign role to the user as given below

```
var user = new User
{
    EmailAddress = email,
    Name = name,
    Surname = surName,
    UserName = email,
    Password = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    TenantId = existingTenant.Id,
    CreatorUserId = AbpSession.UserId
};
user.SetNormalizedNames();

var existingUserId = _userRepository.InsertOrUpdateAndGetId(user);
existingUser = _userRepository.Get(existingUserId);

if (existingRole == null || existingRole.Id == 0)
{
    var newRole = new Role
    {
        DisplayName = role,
        Name = role,
        TenantId = existingTenant.Id,
        CreatorUserId = AbpSession.UserId
    };
    newRole.SetNormalizedName();
    var modifiedRole = _roleRepository.InsertOrUpdateAndGetId(newRole);
}
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(existingUser, role));
CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

*AddToRoleAsync* always results in System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: unitOfWork

I am not sure what could have gone wrong.

Comment: The Error tells you exactly what is wrong with your code, and your snipet does not show us where you assign unitOfWork which is Null when you try to add a Role

Comment: show your full method... I need to see the method definition

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the exception is thrown because of the value of CurrentUnitOfWork. In order to track the issue try to use IUnitOfWorkManager.

```
private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;
...
using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
        {
           //your operation 

            unitOfWork.Complete();
        }
```